# turning nightwatch.js test (using jquery function) into custom assertion or command

Tags: jquery, nightwatch.js

I am currently running a jquery function many times through a test suite in order to validate whether elements are visible in the viewport (nightwatch's current commands like visible, present, etc do not factor this in). This seems like something that would be very valuable to have as a reusable command or assertion, but I fighting an uphill battle to understand how to translate the current code into the new reusable code, and have spent many hours trying different things.

I have other custom commands that work very well, but they do not work on validating the result of a function, they simply perform repeatable commands. Which leads me to believe this should be a custom assertion? The documentation on custom assertions is sparse, and has not helped me in successfully piecing together my own custom assertion.

This is what I run in my test files:

```
browser.execute(function () {
      $.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
        var win = $(window);
        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
    };
      return {
          search: $('.search').isOnScreen(),
          header: $('.gateway-header').isOnScreen()
      };
    }, function (result) {
        browser.verify.equal(result.value.search, false);
        browser.verify.equal(result.value.header, false);
    });
```

So my custom command/assertion would need to be able to call isOnScreen() and validate whether or not it returns true or false. Seems simple? Can anyone help me understand how to go about this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom command to achieve that:

```
  module.exports.command = function(options, callback) {
    var that = this;
    this
    .execute(function () {
      $.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
        var win = $(window);
        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
      };

      var result = [];
      options.forEach( function(element, index) {
          result.push($(element).isOnScreen());
      });

      return result;

    }, function (result) {

        result.value.forEach( function(element, index) {
            that.verify.equal(element, false)
        });
    });
  };
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
client.verifyIfIsOnScreen(['.search', '.gateway-header'])
```